# Can iText retain "Fast web view" or linearized pdf?

Tags: pdf, itext

In page 423 of the book iText in action 2nd ed., it states that:

> "Linearization can only be done after the PDF file is complete and after all resources are known. iText can read linearized PDFs, but it can’t create a linearized PDF, nor can you linearize an existing PDF using iText."

My questions are:

1. What if the existing pdf is already linearized?
2. Can iText retain that?

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: May help you http://support.itextpdf.com/node/142